# Please help me with Wine and other software installation

Tags: installation, software-center, wine, package-management

I cannot install wine on my computer and many other softwares. I have tried synaptic, terminal, and software center. I installed dependcies individually and still get this error though terminal

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Similar errors through synaptic and software center. I have tried suggestion from this website and some other ones but get the same error repeatedly.

Comment: How are you installing Wine?

Comment: though terminal

Comment: I mean what command are you using?

Comment: sudo apt-get install wine

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It should try to resolve any dependency problems, but might remove packages that it can't resolve dependencies for.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  wine-mono0.0.8
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  This is what I got. Should I re-install it?

Comment: Reinstalled it and still got the same error

Comment: No, that just means that wine-mono0.0.8 is currently installed but is not needed.

Comment: yeah but I tried to install wine again and it showed me the same error

Answer (score 0):

To install Wine, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

You may need to install the wine windows compatibility layer 32bit.  Just open the Ubuntu Software Center, and search for wine1.5, and then click install as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: after last command:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.5 : Depends: wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.31-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Look at the additional info in my answer.

Comment: When I install the wine compatibility layer I get the error :

Package dependencies cannot be resolved